# How to get the values in the same column in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

Hi ,

Sorry for blur image! As We can see for Conversion Attrition ,Converted ,Remaining - some values are there!But it's dividing ,I need the values in the same column.

I have done this but the division is coming ! I need help here ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a screenshot, not a photo of your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reduce the number of column headers, remove some discrete (blue) fields from the columns shelf. If you want to reduce the number of row headers, remove some discrete (blue) fields from the rows shelf.

Depending on your data shape and values, you might want to put the fields you take off those shelfs onto another shelf, such as the text shelf.

The easiest approach is treat understanding Tableau as a series of experiments and learn from them -- i.e. if I do this, what does Tableau do in response? In this case, the discrete fields on the rows and columns axis define the row and column headers for your viz, dividing the view into panes and cells.

You have to also keep aware of which fields you are treating as dimensions in your view. That will determine the level of detail of the viz and the number of marks.